# Google Apps Script unusual behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a 5 sheets google spreadsheets and an Apps Script project that in short does this:

```
if (sheetName == "x") {
    var range = sheet.getRange('C2:C23'); // Adjust the range as needed
    var values = range.getDisplayValues();
    return JSON.stringify(values);
  } else if (sheetName == "y"){
    var range = sheet.getRange('E2:E29'); // Adjust the range as needed
    var values = range.getDisplayValues();
    return JSON.stringify(values);
  } else if (sheetName = "z"){//wrong operator
    var range = sheet.getRange('E2:E29'); // Adjust the range as needed
    var values = range.getDisplayValues();
    return JSON.stringify(values);
  }
```

When I call it for x, it successfully returns the correct array. Unfortunately, both for y and z it stops after the first 15 elements. Is there any workaround for this? Why does this happen?

I tried to call 'getValues' instead of 'getDisplayValues'.

Also tried to concatenate smaller chunks with pagination like that:

```
    var values = [];
    var range = sheet.getRange('E2:E' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var chunkSize = 15; // Number of values to retrieve in each chunk

    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i += chunkSize) {
      var chunk = range.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
      values = values.concat(chunk);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(values);
```

However, nothing seems to work. Why does it work only for the x sheetName?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a [mcve]. In this case, you should add a complete function, not only a snippet. Also, you should include some sample data and show what you have tried to debug the code. Note: There is a typo on the third if statment, `sheetName = "z"`, instead of `=` you should use `==` as in the other `if` statement.

Comment: Do you really have three sheets named “x”, “y” & “z”?

Comment: In your third section of your if statement, you’re not using a comparison you’re using an assignment you need to use ==